# Why do i get the victory message right after choosing the first position

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game in the terminal with python but i cant figure out why i get the victory message after choosing the first position can anybody else see why? i have made a for loop to check if i have won in rows or columns and made 2 if statements to check if i have won by diagonal

```
import random

board = [[' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' '],
         [' ',' ',' ']]

def checkwin(board):
   for row in board:
        if len(set(row)) == 1:
           return True 
        elif board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
            return True
        elif board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
            return True
        else:
           return False

def check_space_taken(board, number):
    if not choose_position(board, number) == ' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def choose_position(board, number):
   if number <= 3:
        board[0][number-1] = 'X'
    elif number <= 6:
        board[1][number-4] = 'X'
    elif number <= 9:
        board[2][number-7] = 'X'
    return board, number

def computer_position(board, computer_number):
    computer_number = random.randint(0,9)
    if computer_number <= 3:
        board[0][computer_number-1] = 'O'
    elif computer_number <= 6:
        board[1][computer_number-4] = 'O'
    elif computer_number <= 9:
        board[2][computer_number-7] = 'O'
    return board, computer_number


Game_over = False

while not Game_over:
    print(board)
    player_input = int(input('move to: '))
    changed_board = choose_position(board, player_input)

    for line in changed_board:
        print(line)

    if checkwin(board):
        print('\n-----------------------Congrats you won-----------------------\n')
        Game_over = True
```

Comment: `        if len(set(row)) == 1:
            return True `
Do you know what this does?

Comment: `checkwin` is a disaster for multiple reasons. the thing that makes you win instantly is `len(set(row)) == 1` you forget that `set([' ', ' ', ' '])` is `(' ')` which is of length 1!

Answer (score 0):

In principle, your logic isn't incorrect, but you need to account for empty spaces. You also forgot to check columns:

```
def checkwin(board):
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0] != " " and board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2]:
            return True  # found a winning row
        if board[0][i] != " " and board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i]:
            return True  # found a winning column

    # winning diagonals?
    if board[1][1] != " " and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        return True
    if board[1][1] != " " and board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        return True

    return False
```

Comment: i am confused i used the code that i posted on this question and ran it again and it worked can you tell me why